# Bash to open Browser, scrolldown, then take a screenshots

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, google-chrome, bash

Wanted to know if its possible to do a complex bash.

To simplify our work we are searching for a tool that take screenshots every hour but in different DOM or Scroll position.

They are asking us to be a complete window screen with the clock in of the OS and the window of the browser totally open.

This sounds to me something chaotic or not viable to do, but we were searching for Softwares all around (windows , macos, ubuntu), none of them has what we are looking for.

stillio.io is the nearest tool in the market that do this thing , but the problem is if the website is behind Cloudflare , it will show a Warning so the screenshots is useless.

So we end up looking for a bash command that help us doing this

so far we started with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13436855/launch-google-chrome-from-the-command-line-with-specific-window-coordinates

and

https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

what do you recommend, can We get the next steps:

```
- open chromium-brosers https://thewebsite.io;
- wait until DOM Ready;
- scrollDownUntilSomeDOMElement;
- takeScreenshot;
- waitOneminute;
- closeWindow;
- cron to repeat (but scrolling down to another DOMElement);
```

Comment: You might want to look into Selenium or some other specialized framework.

Comment: please share the website link...i'll find an easy way for you